# How to access a object value of another angular component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

Unfortunately I can't pass data between components.
I took the bcqr-reader demo at 
https://embed.plnkr.co/m9dtF9llcAw7eYE94b5k/preview 
and pass the scanned information to my second component.
First you can see my  scan-component. "$scope.url" is my object of interest.

```
angular.module('foo').component('scan', {
  bindings:{url:"="},
  templateUrl:  'templates/scan.html',
  controller:function($scope){

      $scope.start = function() {
      $scope.cameraRequested = true;
  }

  $scope.processURLfromQR = function (url) {
    $scope.url = url;
    $scope.cameraRequested = false;
  }

  }

});
```

My second component "show" is the destination of "$scope.url".
Later i will need $scope.url to use it as an id for a couchdb query.
I read a lot, about  data exchange between components but i didn't get i running. I also tried to store the object as $rootScope. I would preferre an event based solution like $onChanges, but now every help is welcome.

```
angular.module('foo').component('show', {
template:  '<p> Transfered value: {{$ctrl.url}}</p>',
bindings:{url:"="},
require: { url:'^scan'
},
controller: function () {
this.$onInit = function () {
console.log(this.foo.url); // 
  }; }
```

});

My app.js file looks like:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
var scanState = {
name: 'scan',
url: '/scan',
component:'scan'
}

var showState = {
name:'show',
url: '/show',
component:'show'
}

$stateProvider.state(scanState);
$stateProvider.state(showState);

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("scan");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share stuff between components you may resolve using Services. Services are singleton classes and what you store in them is available throughout your whole application. The thing to keep in mind with singleton classes is that the data stored is not persistent and will be cleared once the app is terminated.

```
app.service('service-name', function(){

   var myVar = undefined;

   var service-name = {
       setVar: function(_value){
            myVar = _value;
       },
       getVar: function(){
            return myVar;
       }
   };       

   return service-name;
});
```

To use the service from a controller just declare it in the controller's dependency and use like so :

form controller A :

var myValue = something;

service-name.setVar(myValue);

from controller B:

var myVar = service-name.getVar();

Comment: Ok thank's for your quick response. Your hint is to extend my state-definintion with an argument. In your case with  "resolve".

Comment: ur welcome! ... "access a object value of another angular component" ..they best way i see to do this is to store the object in an angular service

Comment: let me prepare you the code required to share data through services

Comment: First of all thank you it runs. All examples i knew before used the angular service with "http.get" to read json.files. It is good to know that I can share temporary information like object with angular services too. Furthermore I'am a beginner and i again learned a lot.